# JavaFX ChoiceBox null selection

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'd like to accept null selections on a ChoiceBox control.
By default the selection is null... but, is there any way of making the ChoiceBox control to allow the user to unselect an item once the user selects one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another item with label "*Select...*" and with value `NULL`.